# eSignature create envelope using API and activate the Send UI for manual tagging

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a web based application that allows for authentication and JWT impersonation. I can send a collection of documents and specify signers/recipients all just fine. I am trying to figure out how to get the DocuSign UI to open so the document signature and initials tags can be manually adjusted before the envelope is actually sent.

I have read through the SDK documentation and the QuickStart examples and since I am not using composer, I am not following the basic structures on how to call this UI. Are there any overly simplified code examples that show this process via API calls only and not utilizing a framework, just straight PHP?

Thank you in advance on this...
-greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use embedded sending and there's an [article you can][1] see on how to do that.

Here is the PHP code to get a URL back that you can use to embed the tagging of your envelope in your application:

## Create sender view

```
$view_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\ReturnUrlRequest(['return_url' => $args['ds_return_url']]);
$config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
$config->setHost($args['base_path']);
$config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $args['ds_access_token']);
$api_client = new \DocuSign\eSign\client\ApiClient($config);
$envelope_api = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($api_client);
$results = $envelope_api->createSenderView($args['account_id'], $envelope_id, $view_request);
# Switch to the Recipients / Documents view if requested by the user in the form
$url = $results['url'];
if ($args['starting_view'] == "recipient") {
    $url = str_replace('send=1', 'send=0', $url);
}
return ['envelope_id' => $envelope_id, 'redirect_url' =>  $url];
}
```

**Note:** send=0 or send=1 specifies which page, the recipients selection or tagger is shown to your users first.
[1]: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/embedded-sending/

Comment: The link you provided was perfect and I was able to use the BASH example to better understand the API calls and responses needed to make this work.